# nodejs serialport setCommState

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node-serialport

I am using nodejs serialport with socket.io but after initialization of Serial Port getting SetCommState error. The javascript code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');
var Serialport = require('serialport');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                    response.end();
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                    response.end();
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8001);


io.listen(server);
var listener = io.listen(server);
listener.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    //send data to client
    SerialPort = Serialport.SerialPort;
    serialport = new SerialPort("COM12",{
    baudRate: 9600,
    // look for return and newline at the end of each data packet:
    parser: Serialport.parsers.readline("\n")
     });
    serialport.on('open', function(){
      console.log('Serial Port Opend');
      serialport.on('data', function(data){

            socket.emit('date', {'date': data, 'value': Math.random() });
        });
      });
    serialport.on('error', function(error) {
       console.log('The error: '+error);

    });


    socket.on('client_data', function(data){
        process.stdout.write(data.letter);
      });

});
```

On running the code on command prompt I am getting output as:

```
The error: Error: SetCommState: Unknown error code 31
```

How can I resolve this problem??

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes here looking for this, Error 31 means that windows doesn't have drivers for the product. I was using this to communicate with an Arduino on a friend's Mac, so when I switched to a different Arduino, it worked.

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-31-errors-2623184

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936310/serialport-module-in-node-js-works-only-if-minicom-is-active-on-the-port) issue? Would appreciate any pointers...